# How should I implement generic datagrid for CRUD Operations?

Tags: winforms, crud

I wrote multiple times different apps that have following requirement.

CRUD Operations via DataGrid control...

Everytime I start new prject I write new code for same requirement over and over - what is the best way to make custom DataGrid control which is reusable and generic. I'm a junior developer and I'm having hard time with making reusable code or blocks of code. Especially when it comes to some kind of generic DataGrid control...

Something like just passing DataTable and getting all of the CRUD functionality via generic methods. I usually used RowEditTemplate type forms for Add or Edit.

Is this realistic? Is there a name/method for doing this?

I'm using MSSQL + WinForms + EntityFramework

Should I just get to coding and generate every field via code?

Comment: Yes it possible and name for it "Separation of concerns".

Comment: Did not try it out by myself, but maybe this can help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/SamTomato/database-table-update-in-a-datagridview-without-writing-code/